# How can I edit all the files returned by find in vi in Linux?

Tags: linux, find, vi

Something I find myself doing a lot is running a find command and then editing all of them in vi, which looks something like this:

```
> find . "*.txt"
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
./path/to/file3.txt

> vi ./file1.txt ./file2.txt ./path/to/file3.txt
```

Is there a clever & simple way to do this all in one command line?

Comment: You can pipe it into vi: find . "*.txt" | xargs vi

Comment: @MaQleod: Technically it would be piping to *xargs*.

Comment: Related: [Terminal borked after invoking Vim with xargs](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/410/467).

Comment: Piping to `xargs` destroyed my shell terminal. The proper solution is the one below by @DevSolar

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec vim {} +
```

Use Vim, it's better for your health.  :-)

The oft-overlooked `+` option to `-exec` makes all filenames (up to line length limits) appear in one line, i.e. you still get all the files opened in *one* `vim` session (navigated with `:n` for next and `:N` for previous file).

With `vim -p` you get a file tab for each file. Check `:help tab-page-commands` for more details.

With `vim -o` you will get horizontally split windows for each file, `vim -O` vertically split windows. Check `:help window-move-cursor` for more details.

Note that the previous version of this answer, `vim $(find . -name "*.txt")`, does not work with spaces in filenames, and has security implications.

Piping into `xargs vi` gives a `Warning: Input is not from a terminal`, plus a terminal with completely bogus behaviour afterwards. User grawity explained why in a comment below, and with a bit more explanation in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/336016).

Comment: No need to escape the `*`, globbing won't happen inside the double quotes.

Comment: Just realized that myself when putting it to the test... thanks.

Comment: Don't know how much you know about vim, but it took me /forever/ to figure out that :n shows the next file and :N shows the previous one.

Comment: @DevSolar, your solution was better than mine (now deleted) which tried to execute `vi` through `xargs`, which doesn't work since Vi won't get a terminal for input/output properly.

Comment: @DevSolar: Vim expects its stdin to be the same as its controlling terminal, and performs various terminal-related ioctls on stdin directly. (You could consider this a bug. Vim certainly *can* open `/dev/tty` and call ioctl() on that; it's just too lazy to do it.) When invoked by xargs, vim receives `/dev/null` as its standard input, which just ignores terminal-control ioctls.

Comment: @grawity: *That* explains a *lot*. Thank you very much indeed! You fully deserve a "correct answer" for that, so I made it [a proper question](http://superuser.com/questions/336016/).

Comment: @zpletan: `vim -p` if you want file tabs. (`gt` and `gT` to navigate, or click with your mouse.)

Comment: FYI, to avoid the warning when piping into `vim`, just specify `-` as the first argument, as in `echo foobar | vim -`.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: `find . -name "*.txt" | vim -` gives you a vim session on an unnamed file containing the *names* of the found files, which is not what the OP asked for...

Comment: @DevSolar Well, you still need to use `xargs` (of course).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: "Too many editor arguments". Sorry, it just doesn't work. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: @DevSolar Ah, I see the problem: `vim -` tells `vim` to get the input from STDIN instead of a file. Conversely, with `find` you want to pass multiple arguments to `vim` – quite the opposite. Sorry.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Yeah, it wasn't what I was looking for in this post, but piping command output into a vi buffer is also something I was wondering about. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Or run vim and from there:

```
:args **/*.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if you wanted them opened one at a time, you can also use find -exec or use a simple for loop. 
*Edited per ceving's comment.*

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec vi {} \;
```

or

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for i in `find . -name "*.txt"`
    do
        vi $i
    done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: ...but why would you want to do that?

Comment: @DevSolar The first is to point out the capability in find, the second is a general purpose loop. Maybe you want to do something to every file before you edit it.

Comment: Have you ever tried the second? First: the find returns the current directory because `-name` is missing. And second: the command fails miserably as soon as a file name contains a space. -1 for ill-advised answer.

Comment: Actually, the subject of spaces in filenames applies to my answer just as well. I cannot even think of a way to handle them properly without turning it from a command line into a little script of its own. There is a good reason why spaces in filenames are discouraged.

Comment: @ceving A valid point. I presumed the original posters find was valid for his needs. Editing.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already typed out your `find` command I find that it can be much easier to use `xargs` to open the search results:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs vim -p
```

The `-p` option tells vim to open each file in a new tab. I find this more convenient than just using buffers, but if you don't then just leave off that option.

Comment: thank you I connected it to locate so my command was: locate filename |  xargs vim -p

Answer (score 1):

To edit all `*.txt`, you can just run: `vim *.txt`. To edit files returned by `find`, read futher.

---

On Unix/macOS, you can use `find` with BSD `xargs` (see: `man xargs`), e.g.

```
find -L . -name "*.txt" -type f -print0 | xargs -o -0 vim
```

> `-o` (`xargs`): Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before executing the command.

Related: [Terminal borked after invoking Vim with xargs](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/410/467) at Vim.SE.