# Invoking vi through find | xargs breaks my terminal. Why?

Tags: vim, find

When invoking `vim` through `find | xargs`, like this:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs vim
```

you get a warning about

```
Input is not from a terminal
```

and a terminal with pretty much broken behaviour afterwards. **Why** is that?

---

This question was explicitly about the *why*, not about the *how to avoid*. This was asked, and answered, [elsewhere](http://superuser.com/questions/335999).

Comment: Side note:  You can perform this operation entirely within vim, not using `find` or `xargs` at all.  Open vim with no arguments, then run `:args **/*.txt<CR>` to set vim's arguments from inside the editor.

Comment: @TrevorPowell: In all these years, vim never ceased to amaze me.

Comment: Related: [`grep -l .. | xargs vim` generates a warning, why?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77395/grep-l-xargs-vim-generates-a-warning-why) at unix SE

Comment: Related: [Terminal borked after invoking Vim with xargs](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/410/467) at Vim SE.

Comment: GitHub bug report: [vim does not handle STDIN set to /dev/null](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/982).

Answer (score 116, accepted):

When you invoke a program via `xargs`, the program's stdin (standard input) points to `/dev/null`. (Since xargs doesn't know the *original* stdin, it does the next best thing.)

```
$ true | xargs filan -s
    0 chrdev /dev/null
    1 tty /dev/pts/1
    2 tty /dev/pts/1

$ true | xargs ls -l /dev/fd/
```

Vim expects its stdin to be the same as its controlling terminal, and performs various terminal-related *[ioctl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl)*'s on stdin directly. When done on `/dev/null` (or any non-tty file descriptor), those ioctls are meaningless and return ENOTTY, which gets silently ignored.

- My guess at a more specific cause: On startup Vim reads and remembers the old terminal settings, and restores them back when exiting. In our situation, when the "old settings" are requested for a non-tty fd (file descriptor), Vim receives all values empty and all options disabled, and carelessly sets the same to your terminal.

  You can see this by running `vim < /dev/null`, exiting it, then running `stty`, which will output a whole lot of `<undef>`s. On Linux, running *`stty sane`* will make the terminal usable again (although it *will* have lost such options as `iutf8`, possibly causing minor annoyances later).

You could consider this a bug in Vim, since it *can* open `/dev/tty` for terminal control, but doesn't. (At some point during startup, Vim duplicates its stderr to stdin, which allows it to read your input commands – from a fd opened for writing – but even that is not done early enough.)

Comment: +1, and for TL;DR people just run `stty sane`

Comment: @rahmanisback: The other answers, plus Trevor's comment, all provided ways to avoid terminal breakage in the first place. I accepted grawity's answer, because my question was "why", not "how to avoid" -- that's covered by [another question](http://superuser.com/questions/335999) that actually **spawned** this one.

Comment: @DevSolar Understood, but think about frustrated people like me who just google how to get rid of that behavior while not -unfortunately - have enough time right now to study "why", which is very interesting nonetheless.

Comment: when my terminal breaks, like this, i use `reset` instead of `stty sane` and it works fine after that.

Answer (score 186):

(Following on from grawity's explanation, that `xargs` points `stdin` to `/dev/null`.)

The *solution* for this problem is to add the `-o` parameter to `xargs`. 
From [`man xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html):

> **`-o`**
>
>     Reopen stdin as
>     `/dev/tty`
>     in the child process 
>               before executing the command.  This is useful 
>               if you want
>     `xargs`
>     to run an interactive application.

Thus, the following line of code should work for you:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -o vim
```

GNU xargs supports this extension since some release in 2017
(with the long option name `--open-tty`).

For older or other versions of xargs,
you can explicitly pass in `/dev/tty` to solve the problem:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs bash -c '</dev/tty vim "$@"' ignoreme
```

(The `ignoreme` is there to take up $0,
so that $@ is all arguments from xargs.)

Comment: How would you create a bash alias out of this? `$@` doesn't seem to be translating arguments correctly.

Comment: @zanegray -- you can't make an alias, but you can make it a function. Try: `function vimin () { xargs sh -c 'vim "$@" < /dev/tty' vim; }`

Comment: For a detailed explanation of how the GNU xargs solution works, and why you need the dummy `ignoreme` string, see https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17813

Comment: @zanegray, You can make it an alias. The quotes are tricky. See solution at https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17813

Comment: `The -J, -o, -P and -R options are non-standard FreeBSD extensions which may not be available on other operating systems.` (It was not available on macOS for me because I installed xargs from homebrew (the GNU one))

Comment: GNU xargs has `-o` since [some release in 2017](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158334/xargs-invalid-option-o).

Comment: `vimgrep ()  {  fgrep --no-messages "$@" | xargs -o -p vim }`

Comment: `fgrep ()  {  rgrep --color=never -l "$@" }`

Comment: `rgrep () { if [[ $(argc "$@") < 2 ]]; then dir='./'; else dir=''; fi; GREP_COLOR='35;1' nice grep -rHIin --no-messages --color=always "$@" $dir --exclude-dir='*.vimbackup' --exclude-dir='.svn' --exclude-dir='target' --exclude-dir='.git' --exclude-dir='platforms' --exclude-dir='node_modules' --exclude='*.tmp' --exclude='*~' --exclude='*.min.*' --exclude='.vlt' --exclude='*.swp' | grep -v '^.{1000}' }`

Comment: `argc ()  {  count=0; for arg in "$@"; do if [[ ! "$arg" =~ ^- ]]; then count=$(($count+1)); fi; done; echo $count }`

Comment: vimgrep will recursively search for text in the current directory tree and open each matching file in vim

Answer (score 34):

The easiest way:

```
vim $(find . -name "*foo*")
```

Comment: The main question was "why", not "how to avoid it", and it's been answered to satisfaction two and a half years ago.

Comment: This, of course, does not work properly when filenames contain spaces or other special characters, and is also a security risk.

Comment: My favorite answer because it works for every command that lists files, not just "find" or wildcards. It does require a little trust, as Dejay points out.

Comment: This is will not work with many use cases xargs is designed for: e.g., when the number of paths is very high (cc @TravisWilson)

Answer (score 24):

It should work just fine if you use the -exec option on find rather than piping into xargs.

```
find . -type f -name filename.txt -exec vi {} +
```

Comment: Huh... the trick there is the `+` (instead of "the usual" `\;`) to get all the found files into *one* Vim session -- an option I *keep* forgetting about. You are right, of course, and +1 for that. I use `vim $(find ...)` simply out of habit. However, I was actually asking for *why* the pipe operation screws up the terminal, and grawity nailed that with his explanation.

Comment: This is the best answer and it works on both BSD/OSX/GNU/Linux.

Comment: Also, find is not the only way of getting a list of files that have to be edited simultaneously by vim. I can use grep to find all files with a pattern and try editing them at the same time as well.

Answer (score 11):

Use GNU Parallel instead:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | parallel -j1 --tty vim
```

Or if you want to open all the files in one go:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | parallel -Xj1 --tty vim
```

It even deals correctly with filenames like:

```
My brother's 12" records.txt
```

Watch the intro video to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Comment: Not ubiquitously available. Most of the day I am working on servers where I am not at liberty to install additional tools. But thanks for the hint anyway.

Comment: If your are at liberty to do 'cat > file; chmod +x file' then you can install GNU Parallel: It is simply a perl script. If you want man pages and such, you can install it under your homedir: ./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install

Comment: OK, tried that - but parallel does *not* open all the files, it does open them *in succession*. It's also quite a mouthful for a simple operation. `vim $(find . -name "*.txt")` is simpler, and you get all files opened at once.

Comment: @DevSolar: Somewhat unrelated, but both `find | xargs` and `$(find)` will have big problems with spaces in file names.

Comment: @grawity Correct, but there is no easy way around it (that I know of). You'd have to start fiddling with `$IFS`, `-print0` and stuff, and then you left the realm of a one-shot command line solution and reached a point where you should come up with a script... there's a reason why spaces in filenames are discouraged.

Comment: @grawity Using `find | xargs -d '\n'` works with filenames with spaces in them; it makes `xargs` only split on line-breaks, which works because `find` handily emits filenames on per line. (Obviously it wouldn't work with filenames that have line-breaks in them.)

Answer (score 0):

maybe not the best but here it the script I use (named `vim-open`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'shellwords'

inputs = (ARGV + (STDIN.tty? ? [] : STDIN.to_a)).map(&:strip)
exec("</dev/tty vim #{inputs.flatten.shelljoin}")
```

will work with `vim-open a b c` and `ls | vim-open` for instance

Comment: As for several other answers, note that the actual question was "why", not "how to avoid it". (For which I would still point to Trevor's comment under my question as the most solid way that doesn't require scripting, aliases or anything.)