# open files in vim through xargs modification

Tags: vim, grep

Using a discovery command utility I can grep the location of some directories, and I need to open containing files. I cannot use find with exec such as [this example](https://superuser.com/a/336003/503062) `find . -name "*.txt" -exec vim {} +`.

If I don't modify the grep output, xargs works as this

```bsh
searchUtilityCommand | grep keyword | xargs vim
```

But I actually need

```bsh
searchUtilityCommand | grep keyword | xargs -I % vim %/extra/path
```

However, when doing that it opens the first hit, and after I close it opens the second; close it and open the third... I tried using

```bsh
searchUtilityCommand | grep keyword | xargs -P 0 -I % vim %/extra/path
```

But it just fails. I also tried

```bsh
vim `searchUtilityCommand | grep keyword | xargs -P 0 -I % vim %/extra/path`
```

No luck.

I thought `awk` or `sed` could be used, but I am not fluent with them and I dont know if its worth it. It could be something like

```bsh
searchUtilityCommand | grep keyword | <awk modify grepped path> | xargs vim
```

Any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not tested this, but no reason it should not work:

```
searchUtilityCommand | grep keyword | sed -e 's,$,/extra/path' | xargs vim
```

I have to say though, I don't know how to get rid of the "Warning: Input is not from a terminal" message that comes up when you run vim like this.  (I generally prefer `vim $(command pipeline)` for that reason).

Comment: you where missing a comma at the end of sed regex. Works like a charm! thanks `searchUtilityCommand | grep keyword | sed -e 's,$,/extra/path,' | xargs vim`

Answer (score 0):

From Vim, run this Ex command:

```
:args `=systemlist('searchUtilityCommand | awk ''/keyword/{print $0 "/extra/path"}''')`
```

Or this one:

```
:args `=map(filter(systemlist('searchUtilityCommand'), {_,v -> v =~# 'keyword'}), {_,v -> v.'/extra/path'})`
```

This should populate the arglist with a list of file paths; the ones output by `searchUtilityCommand`, matching `keyword`, with `/extra/path` appended at the end.

From there you can do all sort of things, such as:

```
" open each file in a horizontal split (run `:only` to close all splits except the current one)
:all

" open each file in a vertical split
:vert all

" open each file in a tab page (run `:tabonly` to close all tab pages except the current one)
:tab all

" diff all the files
:vert all | windo diffthis

" replace all occurrences of `pat` with `rep` in each file
:argdo %s/pat/rep/g | update
```

For more information, see:

```
:h `=
:h systemlist(
:h map(
:h filter(
:h :all
:h :argdo
```

Comment: I marked the other answer as the solution for coherence with the question title (for future records), which funnily enough says to prefer using vim commands. This answer has full of potential tips. Thank you!!